# wxPython GUI crashing due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: thread-safety, wxpython

I have read that pub/sub mechanism is a thread-safe mean of communicating from a thread to a GUI ( https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/ )

The program below, which has been reduce from a bigger one to the essence of the problem, crashes after a number of writings from the thread to the `wx.TextCtrl` area of the GUI through the pub/sub mechanism. For experimenting several writing rates, it can be changed in the `time.sleep(x)` statement. Whatever `x` is, it crashes (tested by myself from 0.1 to 100 seconds), it is not a matter of how frequently the thread writes to the GUI.

Basically, the GUI creates the text control and subscribes to a pub/sub mechanism. The thread writes periodically into the publisher. It works fine until crashing with exception:

```
2017-10-21 13:50:26.221 Python[20665:d07] An uncaught exception was raised
2017-10-21 13:50:26.222 Python[20665:d07] NSMutableRLEArray insertObject:range:: Out of bounds
2017-10-21 13:50:26.222 Python[20665:d07] ([…])
2017-10-21 13:50:26.223 Python[20665:d07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray 
insertObject:range:: Out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:
([…]
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The ‘out of bounds’ probably relates to an index on which I have no access from the Python code…  I am unable to go further. Could anybody help ?

Using `Python 2.7.12` | `wxPython 3.0.2.0`
Running `Mac OS X 10.9.5` | on platform `x86_64`

The code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

__version__ = '04'

import sys
import threading
import time
import platform

try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError ("The wxPython module is required to run this program")

try:
    from pubsub import pub
except ImportError:
    from wx.lib.pubsub import pub


class CrashFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title)

        self.hor_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.textlogger = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(520,110), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.VSCROLL, value="" )
        self.hor_sizer.Add(self.textlogger)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.hor_sizer)
        self.Show(True)

        self.crashthread = SocketClientThread()

        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.logthistext('Using Python {} | wxPython {}'.format(sys.version.split()[0], wx.VERSION_STRING))
        self.logthistext('Is thread running ? - %s' % self.crashthread.isAlive())

        # Create a listener in the GUI form
        pub.subscribe(self.logthistext, 'fromSocketListener')

    def logthistext(self, msg):
        self.textlogger.AppendText('{}\n'.format(msg)) # a good way to write on the text area


class SocketClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SocketClientThread, self).__init__()
        self.alive = threading.Event()
        self.alive.set()
        self.start() # thread will start at creation of the class instance

    def run(self):
        while self.alive.isSet():
            data = 'A bunch of bytes'
            pub.sendMessage('fromSocketListener', msg=data)
            time.sleep(10) # or 0.1 or 100, whatever, it crashes
            continue



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = CrashFrame(None,-1,'Crash Program - v{}'.format(__version__))
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

wxPython’s Threadsafe Methods

wx.PostEvent
wx.CallAfter
wx.CallLater

```
def run(self):
    x=0
    while self.alive.isSet():
        data = 'A bunch of bytes-'+str(x)
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage,'fromSocketListener', msg=data)
        time.sleep(0.2) # or 0.1 or 100, whatever, it crashes
        x +=1
```

Comment: Thank you Rolf. It works fine. Great ! What I understand is that pub/sub mechanism is not thread-safe by itself. CallAfter or CallLater are the actual thread-safe mean.